# Why isn't DockBarX in the official repositories?

Tags: repository, official-repositories, dockbarx

Why isn't DockBarX in the official repositories?

(I am aware of the existence of PPAs.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because nobody with the skills to package it for Ubuntu has been motivated to volunteer their time to do so.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+bug/876779